# (Done) Req to reopen I told off a consultant and it affected my job

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

[I told off a consultant and it affected my job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/160873/i-told-off-a-consultant-and-it-affected-my-job)

This is a simple question about correcting course after misconduct.  We handle these all the time, and while this one was a bit ranty, it still does come under our purview.

Subjects like this come under workplace conduct and should, IMO be addressed here, and it is addressable as two of us have addressed it.

Also, the volume here has dropped so much that I think we can, at least at this time, address some of the more borderline ones, or at least edit them into something answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reads to me like a question specifically geared for the HNQ, and not a real situation.  However if the community votes to reopen it, I won't stand in the way.

Comment: I tried toning it down a bit, because it did sound like it needed some fine tuning.

Comment: I'm dubious as well honestly but @Old_Lamplighter's edit was good and it's an answerable and realistic question. As it was on 3 reopen votes I cast a final binding one.

Comment: So very interesting.  I never knew there was discussion about my discussion.

To settle the matter, yes, this really happened.  The aftermath is that I got laid off about a month later.  The given reason was "COVID cutbacks" but we all knew the real reason.

Since the incident, I've been struggling in a dead-end job and kind of given up on my career.  I think about this incident a lot and always wonder if I could have done things differently.